# ajax POST array with multiple email to php for verification, but verification/PHP Function is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

actually I'm sending an array that contains multiple array to PHP with ajax for verification {logged-in or logged-out}.

HTML/JQ:

```
 var arr = ['one@one.com','two@two.com','three@three.com',four@four.com' ....];
 $.ajax({
   url: "verify.php?action=email",
   type: "post",
   data: "email="+arr,
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
     alert(response.status);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
     alert(textStatus);
   }
 });
```

PHP:

```
 define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
 include('functions.php');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $data = array();

 switch($_GET['action']) {
   case 'email':
     $items[] = explode(',', $_POST['email']);
     foreach($items as $key){
       $n[] = getStatus($key); // getStatus function is defined in "functions.php"
     }
     $data['status'] = $n;
   break;
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
```

Now the problem is: it returns null every time, instead of "online" or "offline". but works good if I just pass the single email. like:

```
 $n = getStatus('one@one.com');
 $data['status'] = $n;
```

any solution....

thnks & regards

UPDATE:

its works when array is manipulated manually :

```
  $items = array('one@one.com','two@two.com'....);
    foreach($items as $key){
      $n = getStatus($key);
      $data['status'] = $n;
  }
```

and a `for loop` in ajax `success` function.

but i want to pass the array from jquery to php

UPDATE : ANSWER

```
 $items = explode(',', $_POST['email']);
 foreach($items as $key){
   $data['status'][] = getStatus($key);
 }
```

with jQ:

```
 success: function(response){
   for(var i in response.status){
     alert(response.status[i]);
   }
 },
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: My function foo returns a null, why?.. Why hide you `getStatus` implementation?

Comment: First thing is `$n[]` getting an array or a value because if its a value it will overwrite on each iteration of the loop. Second, Are you sure you dont need to use JSON.stringify on browser side and json_decoded on server side to pass json string?

Comment: @vp: `getStatus` should return "online" or "offline". and I didn;t this code, bcz this is not necessary

Comment: @Sebastien: is `$n[]` overwritting the value, than at least its should have one right value base on last email/any.
No, I don't think that I have to use anyone of them bcz its works good. (except this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't really clear to me what you try to do.

Something like this?

```
 define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $data = array();
 $items = array();

 switch($_GET['action']) {
   case 'email':
     $items = explode(',', $_POST['email']);
     foreach($items as $key){
       $data['status'][] = "bar"; // getStatus function is defined in "functions.php"
     }
   break;
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
```

Sends an array of all Statuses back to jQuery.

Tested locally and worked with your html code.
Response was:

```
{"status":["bar","bar","bar","bar"]}
```

It isn't really clear to me if you want to send an array with all statuses to jQuery or just one status?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
 $items[] = explode(',', json_decode($_POST['email']));
```

assuming your function works that should work fine.

**EDIT**

```
switch($_GET['action']) {
case 'email':
    $items[] = explode(',', $_POST['email']);
    $n = array(); //add this
    for($x=0;$x<count($items);$x++){
        $n[$x] = getStatus($key); // getStatus function is defined in "functions.php"
     }
    //$data['status'] = $n;
    break;
 }

 echo json_encode($n);
```

return all the other code to normal but change `alert(response.status);` to `alert(response);`

Comment: Right - `print_r($n)` instead of echoing $data and see what you get.

Comment: `print_r($n)` : `parsererror : SyntaxError : JSON.parse: unexpected character`
and
`print_r json_encode($data);` : `error:Internal Server Error`

Comment: `echo json_encode($data);` -> `print_r($n);` - and change to`alert(response);`

Comment: `print_r($n)` with `alert(response)` and '`print_r($n)` with `alert(response.status)` => `parsererror : SyntaxError : JSON.parse: unexpected character`

i think this is due to `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: the problem is that your AJAX is expecting a JSON response - remove the `dataType: "json",` and manually create JSON `var arr = JSON.stringify(`

Comment: `var arr = JSON.stringify('one@one.com','two@two.com'.....);` + `dataType` and `cache` is removed from the ajax call.
RESULT : `alert(response+" - "+response.status);` => `object : object -  `

Comment: instead of alert use console.log() -> then F12 to open console

Comment: I'm using `firebug` : and `console.log(response);` shows nothing

Comment: in your edited answer, where is the `$key`? as mentioned in `getStatus($key);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the status of the response using something like F12 tools? It could be that your PHP is erroring out and never returning a value (besides a 500 status code), and this is probably why:

```
data: "email="+arr
```

`arr` is a JavaScript array, like `['blah1','blah2','blah3']`. When converted to a string, you get `blah1,blah2,blah3`.

Since you're passing in arr appended to `"email="`, you end up with something like `email=one@one.com,two@two.com,three@three.com`. Since you're passing in a `string` as your `data` value, JQuery is probably feeding that right through as a raw POST body, and PHP is probably having a difficult time parsing it.

If you use this syntax, it should work as expected:

```
 var arr = ['one@one.com','two@two.com','three@three.com',four@four.com' ....];
 $.ajax({
   url: "verify.php?action=email",
   type: "post",
   data: { email: arr.toString() },
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
     alert(response.status);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
     alert(textStatus);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Can you open the F12 tools and see what kind of response is coming back from the server?